# Ordenar data frames por valor numérico para poder unirlos con rbind - Resuelto!

Tags: r, dataframe, binding, ordenar

tengo que unir 60 dataframes llamados coord1, coord2, coord3, ... , coord60.

para ello hago lo siguiente:

`new_df <- do.call("rbind",mget(ls(pattern = "^coord")))`

el problema es que me une los data frame pero en lugar de hacerlo por el orden lógico de los números desde 1 hasta 60 lo hace en el siguiente orden:

coord1, coord10, coord11, coord12..., coord19, coord2,coord20,...

¿cómo podría solucionar esto y que los ordene coord1, coord2, coord3,... coord60?

Muchas gracias

Ya me han explicado cómo hacerlo. Dejo por aquí las instrucciones por si puede ayudar a alguien:

```
new.df <- mget(ls(pattern="^coord"))
new.df <- new.df[ order(as.integer(gsub("\\D", "", names(new.df)))) ]
do.call(rbind, new.df)
```